# Link inside php_e

Tags: php, html, wordpress

```
 <?php _e('Copyright-, All rights reserved | Build by this *company- this is the word I want to href*','theme'); ?>
```

I want to link a word on this phrase, but i dont know what is php_e and how to a href this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your Code to

```
<?php _e('Copyright-, All rights reserved | Build by this ','theme');?><a href="#"><?php _e('Company','theme');?></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

_e is used to translate output.

Here the doc : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e

You can just link your word inside, it's not a problem.

Comment: If it works, please consider validating it as the correct answer, for next guys that need the same thing. Thank you! Nice to see it works for you.